# How do I make an empty array in a soap request using SUDS

Tags: python, soap, suds

The SOAP request I'm making requires an array of strings and for some requests it should be empty. The XML should look like this (created in [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)):

```
<ns0:instanceNames>
<!--Zero or more repetitions:--> 
</ns0:instanceNames>
```

So I tried making that xml element with [SUDS](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki) like this:

```
instanceNames = client.factory.create('ns2:ArrayOfstring')
instanceNames.string = []
result = client.service.GetStuff(instanceNames=instanceNames)
```

But when I send the request, the element is not there in the XML at all. There are no  tags and as a result my request fails.

However, if I add a single element, even an empty string, the surrounding array tags appear and the request succeeds. For example:

```
instanceNames = client.factory.create('ns2:ArrayOfstring')
instanceNames.string = [""]
```

produces:

```
<ns0:instanceNames>
<ns1:string></ns1:string>
</ns0:instanceNames>
```

But I'd rather not have that empty inner element.

Am I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing something:

```
instanceNames.string = [None]
```

or even:

```
instanceNames.string.append(None)
```